# Pagination in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic framework for app development. I can fetch the list of customer from db but list is large that's why i want to load that list slowly like want to display data in some portion then again display next data like Lazy loading can anyone please suggest me the various options for this or any links or examples for my problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use ionic infinite scroll, it is used to handle pagination , here is documentation for the infinite scroll https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Here is a good link for practical understanding: http://sunnycyk.com/2014/02/ionic-framework-infinite-scrolling/ 
Purpose of ionic infintie scroll is to load only that amount of items which fit to screen, and scroll to load more.The ionInfiniteScroll directive allows you to call a function whenever the user gets to the bottom of the page or near the bottom of the page.